# How to rotate the second hand of the clock with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, clock, qpainter, qpixmap

I am using the code below to try to rotate the pointer simulating the second hand of the clock, but when he turns it cuts, the square of the background is fixed and it seems I'm not able to rotate all:

```
   QPixmap shipPixels(":/new/prefix1/imagem/ponteiro.png");
   QPixmap rotatePixmap(shipPixels.size());
   rotatePixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

   QPainter p(&rotatePixmap);

   p.translate(rotatePixmap.size().width() / 2, rotatePixmap.size().height() / 2);
   p.rotate(90);
   p.translate(-rotatePixmap.size().width() / 2, -rotatePixmap.size().height() / 2);

   p.drawPixmap(0, 0, shipPixels);
   p.end();

   shipPixels = rotatePixmap;
   ui->label->setPixmap(rotatePixmap);
```

The pointer looks like this:

[image: Pointer]
Now with it rotated 90 º
[image: With 90º]

Comment: The first image shows the entire pointer without application of rotation and the second image shows only a small piece of the pointer and that was after the rotation was applied. The impression is that he's taking only one piece of the pointer when it spins the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt Analog Clock example:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html

Maybe before rotating `QPixmap`s, try drawing a line.  After the line is in place and drawing correctly work backwards from there.

UPDATE:

Some sample code for rotating images.

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QTime>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
private:
    QPixmap bg;
    QPixmap second_hand;
    QTime time;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    time.restart();
    this->resize(256, 256);
    // both images are 256x256 in this example
    bg.load("./images/bg.png");
    second_hand.load("./images/second_hand.png");
    QTimer * t = new QTimer;
    t->setSingleShot(false);
    t->setInterval(15);
    QObject::connect(t,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    t->start();
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawPixmap(QPoint(0,0),bg);
    qreal seconds = ((qreal)(time.elapsed() % 60000))/1000;
    p.translate(this->width()/2, this->height()/2);
    p.rotate(seconds/60*360);
    p.drawPixmap(QPoint(-this->width()/2, -this->height()/2),second_hand);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my case I have already designed the clock, just need to figure out how to turn the hands, then this example there is not much help.

Comment: The pointer is spinning, but it does not stay in the center as it rotates it changes position. Where dumb for him to stay with one of the fixed points and thus rotate around the circle? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I think I found the problem, but all the tests I was doing was outside the paintEvent reading and saw that only works if you are into this, but only found out because of your help, so thank you.